# Should I Escape Forward and Backslashes?

Tags: regex

Should I allow users to key in "/" and "\" as input?

Example, a company role may be President/CEO. I am sure there are other cases where a user wants to legitimately use a forward slash and/or a back slash (like I just did).

UPDATE:
Used in the context of: users will be able to key in things they want to do

Comment: In what context?  If your program is a word processor, I'd better be able to use both!

Comment: @Carl Norum See update.

Comment: I don't really see how your update clarifies anything. Why slashes? Why not the `@` character too? What about `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I allow users to key in "/" and "\" as input?

Yes.